# How to fix broken intent-filter in Android 8

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, android-8.0-oreo

Since updating the target SDK to 26 and testing on a Android 8.1 device, tapping on an email attachment (our file extension) in GMail no longer opens our app activity.

I believe it's due to support for implicit intents in Android 8 being removed, but can't identify an alternative approach.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.abc.RestoreActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <!-- Filter to open file with gmail version < 4.2 -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/fileextn" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.fileextn" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Filter to open file with gmail version 4.2 -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.fileextn" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Tapping the email attachment in GMail now opens the GMail dialog showing "Fetching attachment..." with progress bar running - and it never stops until canceled.

Alternatively, if I download the file and then open it from download manager.. it opens our app fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:scheme="content"
        tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.fileextn" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly it didn't change the behavior.